# How do I access private properties from within public methods in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object)

I wanted to create a "class" in JavaScript which other "classes" should inherit from.

Thus, I added "public methods" using the prototype object.

Inside these methods, I want to access private properties of my class.

It seems like I cannot access them. How do I do this? This is my code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>OOP test</title>

        <script>

            var ParentClass = function(){
                var data = [];
            }

            ParentClass.prototype.addData = function(somedata){
                data.push(somedata); // ReferenceError: Can't find variable: data
            }

            var p = new ParentClass();
            p.addData("foo");

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<head>
    <title>OOP test</title>

    <script>

        var ParentClass = function(){
            this.data = [];
        }

        ParentClass.prototype.addData = function(somedata){
            this.data.push(somedata); // ReferenceError: Can't find variable: data
        }

        var p = new ParentClass();
        p.addData("foo");

    </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no public or private (not even when you quote them), there is just object properties and variables. You cannot access variables that are not in scope. The `.addData` method is defined out of scope of `data` variable.

Object properties can be accessed as long as you have a reference to the object, so make it an object property:

```
var ParentClass = function(){
    this.data = [];
}

ParentClass.prototype.addData = function(somedata){
    this.data.push(somedata);
}
```

Comment: The call of `data.push(somedata);` also needs to be changed to `this.data.push(somedata);`

Comment: @valmar yeah thanks, I forgot that in other languages (C#, java, where the OP is most likely coming from) `this` is optional so it would not be obvious

Answer (score 0):

It throws a reference error because the variable 'data' is 'private' to the function 'ParentClass'.. to simulate the functionaility you could use a closure type method.

```
var ParentClass = function(){
    var data = [];
    this.addData = function(somedata){
        data.push(somedata); // Closure will have access to all variables in 'ParentClass'
    }
}
```

However this will intefere with the prototypical inheritance you seem to be wishing to implement.